# WCF start failure message box

Tags: wcf, service

I have a WCF project using C#, Visual Studio. When i want to start my project in debug mode i have this error: "Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. ...". I shouln't install my service using installutil program.

[image]

In my code i have a wrapper for starting program in debug mode to prevent this error:

```
#if DEBUG
    MyService service = new MyService();
    service.MyMethod();         
#else
    ServiceBase[] services;
    services= new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new MyService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(services);
#endif
```

But error is still there. It appears before going inside to the method MyMethod() [F11]

Comment: Basically, you sould not see the error you see if `ServiceBase.Run` is really not called. Try setting a breakpoint inside your `#if DEBUG` code; make sure it is actually run. Other than that, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications) for more information.

Comment: The code which you mentioned here should work fine in debug mode.
From my point of view the best approach is, move the business logic into separate  project and  have separate console app, to test the logic

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, please make sure that the account running the window service has the required permissions, preferably using localsystem, which could be configured in the **ServcieProcessInstaller**.
If the service needs to interact with the database, you can use a specific user to run the service so that the service can properly connect to the database.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.